# Authentication for angular 5

Tags: angular, authentication, angular5

Excuse me for the big chunks of code I have no idea how to make it more compact as I don't know what I did wrong. So I made an angular 5 app and I made an `admin-login-component.ts` on route /admin with a simple form login with the action to log in which lets you go to another route /admin/overview and I block non logged in user to go to admin/overview and redirect them to /admin but somewhere along the line I screwed up and now when I log in I see the route change to /admin/overview but I still see the admin component, what did I miss?

app-routing.module.ts

```
{
path: 'admin',
component: AdminLoginComponent,
data: {title: 'Admin'},
children: [
  {
    path: 'overview',
    component: AdminOverviewComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data: {title: 'Overview'}
  }
]
}
```

admin-login-component.ts

```
export class AdminLoginComponent{

constructor(private router: Router, private service: AuthService){}


loginUser(e) {
e.preventDefault();
let username = e.target.elements[0].value;
let password = e.target.elements[1].value;

if(username == 'test' && password == 'test'){
  this.service.login();
  this.router.navigate(['admin/overview']);
}
}

}
```

auth.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
isLoggedIn = false;

 // store the URL so we can redirect after logging in
 redirectUrl: string;

 login(): Observable<boolean> {
 return Observable.of(true).delay(1000).do(val => this.isLoggedIn = true);
 }

 logout(): void {
  this.isLoggedIn = false;
 }
}
```

auth-guard-service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): 
boolean {
    let url: string = state.url;

    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.canActivate(route, state);
  }

  checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }

    // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
    this.authService.redirectUrl = url;

    // Navigate to the login page with extras
    this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a router outlet in your admin LoginComponent?

Comment: no only the app.router, is it better to have a router outlet in the login?

Comment: No, but it could have been a cause why you see the other component on the login's page. DId you try my answer below?

Comment: I'm at work currently and npm i doesn't go through the proxy so I have to set proxy settings but I'm a noob for things like this so any clue how I define and find the proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the routing to

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  component: AdminLoginComponent,
  data: {title: 'Admin'}
},
{
  path: 'admin/overview',
  component: AdminOverviewComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  data: {title: 'Overview'}
}
```

where I define the overview as admin/overview instead of a child route it works

Answer (score 1):

In your loginUser method you try to navigate straight away without waiting for the (fake) login process to finish.

So your guard is triggered while the user is not considered logged in yet, which prevents from activating the other component.

Try that

```
this.service.login().subscribe(userIsLoggedIn =>
 this.router.navigate(['admin/overview']));
```

Comment: Since `if(username == 'test' && password == 'test'){
      this.service.login().subscribe(userIsLoggedIn =>
        this.router.navigate(['admin/overview']));
        console.log('test');
    }`
Isn't really a secure way of loggin in how would I go further from this?

Comment: You'd need to pass the username/password to your login service, do real authentication by calling your api, then return a boolean indicating if the login was successful. Then use that boolean in the subcription above to navigate only if login was successful

Comment: That's chinese for me, I do have a firebase db where I can store these values but I have no idea how this would become more secure.

Comment: I found something called Okta and will try to use that for user authorisation

Comment: swapped to AngulareFire's auth and got kind of the same problem now, made a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562303/rerouting-angular-5-app-with-angularfireauth)