# Rerouting angular 5 app with AngularFireAuth

Tags: angular, firebase, routes, angular5, angularfire2

I got the simple authentication working with AngularFireAuth but now my routing doesn't work anymore the console.logs show that the 'test' comes before the 'Nice it worked', so what is wrong? (this is mainly just the [routing guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) out of the documentation)

auth-service

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth){
    this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;
  }
  isLoggedIn = false;

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    this.firebaseAuth
  .auth
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(value => {
    console.log('Nice, it worked!');
    return Observable.of(true).delay(1000).do(val => this.isLoggedIn = true);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Something went wrong:',err.message);
  });
return Observable.of(false).delay(1000).do(val => this.isLoggedIn = false);
}
}
```

login component

```
constructor(private router: Router, private service: AuthService){}
loginUser() {
    this.service.login(this.email, this.password).subscribe(userIsLoggedIn =>
      this.router.navigate(['admin/overview']));
      this.email = this.password = '';
      console.log('test');
  }
```

routing

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  component: AdminLoginComponent,
  data: {title: 'Admin'}
},
{
  path: 'admin/overview',
  component: AdminOverviewComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  data: {title: 'Overview'}
}
```

auth-guard

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
 let url: string = state.url;

 return this.checkLogin(url);
}

canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
 return this.canActivate(route, state);
}

checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
 if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }

 // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
 this.authService.redirectUrl = url;

 // Navigate to the login page with extras
 this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
 return false;
}
```